# Views relationships causes duplicates

Tags: views, theming

[image]

I have a view that shows a list of students and their associated classes (which is an entity reference multi value field).

If you look in the image you see it comes out fine in the first view (except the Class/Group values are currently the node titles / how they appear when you select them on the Student node).

I would like them to show a different field on the "Class" node which is called field_class_name

To do this I add a relationship in then add the field in and use the relationship to bring it into the view. This causes duplicates and I cannot find any way around it.

The outcome of the view should be the same as the first but with the "Class Name" having comma seperated values and not duplicate rows in the results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Views relationship outputting duplicate nodes?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12498/views-relationship-outputting-duplicate-nodes)