# How to remove duplicate nodes in a view with taxonomy relationship (1 node per term)?

Tags: 7, views

I have a fairly straightforward view. Ie. Display nodes that are published & of content type X. Then sort by date.

It does however, have a relationship to a Vocabulary so that I can get access to the taxonomy image to display.

The result is a view that displays duplicate nodes if there is more than one taxonomy term of that vocab tagged on it.

How can I remove these duplicates?

I've tried the Query settings Distinct/Pure Distinct to no avail.

I'm also looking at this, but I'm hoping for a different solution. 
[Views relationship outputting duplicate nodes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12498/views-relationship-outputting-duplicate-nodes)

**Update** I had seen the [Views distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module (suggested in an answer now) and should have added it to the possible solutions. I'm still hoping for a "*I just didn't know how to configure the view properly*" kind of solution, as it feels like there must be a way to do this in Views instead of adding another module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct

use this module and configure the settings in the view Field. 
[image]

This will remove those duplicates from your view. 
do this for the duplicated field items.

Comment: Oh right. I had seen this and should have added it to the possible solutions. I'm still hoping for a "I just didn't know how to configure the view properly" kind of solution, as it feels like there must be a way to do this in views instead of adding another module. But I'll do this for now, as it seems like the best option I can find. Thanks.

Comment: we all had this issue.That's why Drupal View_Distinct module came in. the module description says it all. cheers!

Comment: ahh. Hadn't read that. In good company I guess. :)